# Delete a range of lines in an unix file through a variable

Tags: linux

I want to delete a range of lines in an UNIX file through a variable.
like:
a=38
sed '4,$ad' text.csv >/new file
I tried the above command,but its not working.
Can someone please help me.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    if ( NR < start_index && NR > end_index )
    {
        print $0;
     }
}
```

This is a AWK script. Run this as  follows (change the values of `start_index` and `end_index` as you want.

`awk -f your_script.awk  -v start_index=4 end_index=5 text.csv > new_filename`

So basically you are not copying the lines which falls in the range. After you are done, you can delete the original file using `rm` if you want.

Answer (score 0):

You need double quotes and a space between the environment variable and 'delete' command. You could also make your shell variable names more meaningful:

```
end=38
sed "4,$end d" text.csv > new.csv
```

Comment: Another difference between the OP's and your answer is the space between `$end` and the `d` command.

Comment: Of course. However, my point was that it does not work without the space because then the shell would try to interpolate a variable named `ad` (in the OP's example).